# Write untill i find an empty line in C

Tags: c, do-while, blank-line

I'm trying to find all data for a day (Monday, Tuesday...)  and write the data below.
My txt document is written as:

```
Monday .......
..............
..............

Tuesday.......
..............
..............

Monday........
..............
..............
```

The only thing that is separating days is an empty line.
I successfully find the day in a file, the problem is that I need to print all the data until an empty line occurs.
For instance, if I select Monday(`selectedday="Monday"`), my output should be:

```
Monday .......
..............
..............

Monday .......
..............
..............
```

The code I've tried:

```
    int main()
    {
        char string[100], selectedday[] = "monday"; //for Monday
        FILE* openbill;
        openbill= fopen("bill.txt", "r");
        if (openbill== NULL)
        {
            printf("Failed to open bill\n");
            return NULL;
        }
        while (fscanf(openbill, "%s", string) == 1)
        {
            if (strstr(openbill, selectedday) != 0)
            {
                printf("%s", string);
               
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This post will.help you resolve and understand more about fprintf and fscanf. https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/ . I thunk, you are using a wrong approach.

Comment: instead of `openbill` in `strstr()`, use `string`. Otherwise error will shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scanset `%2[\n]` tells `fscanf` to scan up to two characters and only scan newlines.
The format string `"%99s"` tells `fscanf` to scan up to 99 non-whitespace characters into `string`. This allows room for the terminating zero.
`output` is a flag that is set to `1` when the day is found and set to `0` when a pair of newlines is scanned. A `1` enables output and `string` will be printed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void showday ( char *selectedday) {
    char string[100] = "";
    char newline[3] = "";
    int result = 0;
    int output = 0;
    FILE* openbill = NULL;

    openbill = fopen ( "bill.txt", "r");
    if ( openbill == NULL) {
        perror ( "bill.txt");
        return;
    }
    do {
        string[0] = 0;//set empty string
        if ( 1 == ( result = fscanf ( openbill, "%2[\n]", newline))) {
            if ( output) {//enabled
                printf ( "%s", newline);
            }
            if ( '\n' == newline[1]) {//two newlines
                output = 0;//disable
            }
        }
        else {
            result = fscanf ( openbill, "%99s", string);
            if ( strstr ( string, selectedday)) {
                output = 1;//enable
            }
        }
        if ( output && string[0]) {//enabled and string not empty
            printf ( "%s ", string);
        }
    } while ( EOF != result);

    fclose ( openbill);

}

int main ( void) {

    showday ( "monday");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple issues in your code.
**Mistakes:**

- `strstr(char* array1, char* array2)` compares two string `array1` and `array2`.
  But in the code, you are comparing `openbill` (`FILE*`) to `selectedday` (`char*`) which will result in error.
- You want stop reading information when an empty line(`string=="\n"`) is reached.
  But `fscanf()` doesn't take newline as input and thus skips any empty newline. [read here](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/).
- `fscanf` stops taking input whenever a `space` or `newline` is reached. Which means it can only read a single word, not a `string`(which can contain multiple word separated by `space`)
- Your character array `string` can store max 100 characters. But a single line may contain more characters which may cause overflow.

---

**Possible Solution:**

- `strstr(string, selectedday)` instead of `strstr (openbill, selectedday)`.
- Use `fgets` instead of `fscanf`. It can read newline and thus can take empty line(`"\n"`) as input. It also prevents overflow by limiting the size of input that is taken.

---

**Code:**
Feature of an empty line(`"\n"`) is that its size is 1 `char` long and the `char` is `'\n'`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int getSize(char* charArray) //returns the actual size of an char* array.
{
    int size = 0; //size = number of char before '\0'

    while (charArray[size] || charArray[size]!=NULL)
    {
        size++;
    }
    return( size );
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char string[100], selectedday[]="monday";
    FILE* openbill;
    openbill= fopen("bill.txt", "r");
    if (openbill== NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to open bill\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    while (fgets(string, 100 ,openbill )!=NULL)//EOF not reached and a line is read
    {
        if (strstr(string, selectedday) != 0)
        {
            printf("%s", string);
            while (fgets(string, 100, openbill ) && getSize(string)!=1 && string!="\n") //EOF not reached and string is not an empty line.
            {
                printf("%s", string);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }    
    }
    fclose(openbill);
    return 0;
}
```

Sample Input:

```
..

monday----  -------\n1
d----------------\n2
----------- ---kol

but why?
\n
g

monday  -----------\n1
d-----------  -----\n2

end
g
```

Sample Output:

```
monday----  -------\n1
d----------------\n2
----------- ---kol

monday  -----------\n1
d-----------  -----\n2
```